# Getting "Error Code 8" When Calling [ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType] - iOS Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, acaccount, acaccountstore

I have been searching Google and SO and cannot find what com.apple.accounts Error Code 8 means. I am attempting to use iOS 6 and the Facebook SDK.

I run this request;

```
  if (!_accountStore) _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *fbActType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];


NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey, @"###############",  
                         (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey, [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"],  
                         nil];



[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:fbActType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if (granted) {
                                                NSLog(@"Success");
                                                NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:fbActType];
                                                _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];                                                    
                                            } else {
                                                NSLog(@"ERR: %@",error);
                                                // Fail gracefully...
                                            }
        }
 ];
```

I get this error:

`ERR: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)"`

No matter what I do, `granted` never returns true. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

If I bypass the `if(granted)` and call this function:

```
- (void)me{

    NSLog(@"Home.m - (void)me");

    NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

    SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                        URL:meurl
                                                 parameters:nil];

    merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

    [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", meDataString);

    }];
```

Then I see this JSON that is returned by Facebook:
`{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}}`

**Update:** So, the error means "The client's access info dictionary has incorrect or missing values." but I do not know what that means.

Comment: iPod Touch running iOS 6.0

Comment: Logged into FaceBook in Settings, right?

Comment: Yes. I re-installed the official Facebook app, logged into the Facebook app using the iOS6 account, and the Facebook appeared in my Setting.app within the list of apps in the Facebook section.

Comment: Do you have an 'active access token'?

Comment: Apparently not? I assume that is what `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Are you using `FBSession` anywhere?

Comment: In fact, are you using the Facebook API *from FaceBook* (not built-in iOS) at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29685/discussion-between-chris-and-undo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS requestAccessToAccountsWithType is Not Showing Permission Prompt / NSAlert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469077/ios-requestaccesstoaccountswithtype-is-not-showing-permission-prompt-nsalert)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an error in your options dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey, @"###############",  
                     (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey, [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"],  
                     nil];
```

read better the method declaration: "dictionary with object and keys", so first object, then key...but you have inserted first KEYS and then OBJECTS (wrong order :-)

The correct dictionary is:

```
    NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"###############", ACFacebookAppIdKey, 
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey, 
                         nil];
```

or, declaring dictionary literal:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey : @"###############",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey : [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"]
                             };
```

Comment: Thank you. Definitely one of those "It's too simple" problems.

Comment: In email option we need to specify any mail id