# iOS requestAccessToAccountsWithType is Not Showing Permission Prompt / NSAlert

Tags: ios, facebook, acaccountstore

It is my understanding that when I invoke `[ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion]`, the user is supposed to see an UIAlert that asks them if they grant permission to my app.

When I run this code, there is never a prompt and the `granted` variable is always "false"

```
-(void)myfunction { 
if (!_accountStore) _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *fbActType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];


    NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey, @"##########",  
                             (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey, [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"],  
                             nil];


    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:fbActType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Home.m - getFBDetails - Check 2");
                                                if (granted == YES) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Success");
                                                    NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:fbActType];
                                                    _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];                                                    
                                                    [self me];
                                               } else {
                                                    NSLog(@"ERR: %@ ",error);
                                                    // Fail gracefully...
                                              }
            }
     ];

}
```

And I get the Error: `ERR: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)"`

**Update:** I did some testing and if I run with using `ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter`, I get the prompt to connect to my Twitter accounts, so I am supposing it is something with my Facebook settings ...

Comment: what is the output log ?

Comment: updated original post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Error Code 8" When Calling \[ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType\] - iOS Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425325/getting-error-code-8-when-calling-acaccountstore-requestaccesstoaccountswitht)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inverted objects and keys in your options dictionary :

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"##########",  ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                         nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually missing a key: **ACFacebookAudienceKey**.
You can change it like that:

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey, @"##########",  
                                 (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey, [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"],
                                 (NSString *)ACFacebookAudienceKey, ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,
                                 nil];
```

By the way, when you are using Twitter, the options must be `nil`.