# requestAccessToAccountsWithType Returns NSError of "(NULL)"

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, nserror

I am using this code to connect to Facebook. It works the first time. Then I go into my Settings App and revoke the permissions. Then I go back into my app and run this code again.  `granted` returns `NO` but the `error` does not contain any data, I am expecting error `code 6`, but I am getting `"(null)"`

```
    if (!_accountStore) _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *fbActType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Permissions
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"];
NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"##########", ACFacebookAppIdKey, 
    permissions, ACFacebookPermissionsKey, 
    nil];


    // requestAccessToAccountsWithType
    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:fbActType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted) {
        // do something if we have access
    } else {
          NSLog(@"%@",error); // this returns "(null)"
    }
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm trying to do similar to you -- detect if the user has disallowed access to Twitter after they've initially allowed access. I was expecting a ACErrorPermissionDenied error, but it returns `(null)`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't remember at this point. Might be the same issue I was having here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469077/ios-requestaccesstoaccountswithtype-is-not-showing-permission-prompt-nsalert

Comment: I’m having exactly the same issue.  I have no trouble accessing the Twitter accounts, but this is what happens in the Facebook case.  I’m wondering if perhaps I haven’t set up the Facebook app properly on developers.facebook.com...?

Comment: Found the issue in my case!  See my answer below.  I hope it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just stumbled across the answer in my case.  The answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor) actually helped me find it.

1. I enabled my Facebook app as a native app, in developers.facebook.com (Settings->Advanced.)
2. I made my first request as a read just of @“email”.

   ```
   NSDictionary *options = @{
                             ACFacebookAppIdKey: @“MY_FB_APP_ID",
                             ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"],
                             };
   ```

That seems to "prime the pump” and subsequent requests for other permissions (reads and writes must be requested separately) have worked well.  For example:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @“MY_FB_APP_ID",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email",
                                                      @"user_friends"],
                          };
```