# Uploading video to facebook from iOS -- unable to request log in permission from user, error code 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-framework

I'm using the social framework in iOS 6 to integrate facebook video uploading into my app. However, nothing happens when I run the program, and I instead receive these errors:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)
>
> "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}"

Below is my code, the first half of which I implemented from this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_and_Twitter_Integration_using_SLRequest). `granted` is set to `false`, causing the first error.

```
- (void)uploadToFb {

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                          accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // Specify App ID and permissions
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                               ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"2************",
                               ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                               ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                          options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {

          if (granted) 
          {
              NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
              facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
          }
          else
          { 
           NSLog(@"Error %@", e.localizedDescription);                                              }

          }
    }];

    NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];

    NSString *filePath = [outputURL path];
    NSURL *pathURL = outputURL;
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *params = @{
    @"title": @"Face Puppets Video",
    @"description": @"A funny video I made with the #FacePuppets iOS app."
    };

    SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                            URL:videourl
                                                     parameters:params];
    [uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                           withName:@"source"
                               type:@"video/quicktime"
                           filename:[pathURL absoluteString]];

    uploadRequest.account = facebookAccount;

    [uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
            NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Here it is a very nice Sharing example [iOS (Wiki) (Sample Project for iOS, ~3 MB)](https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion/wiki/How-To-for-iOS) Using this you can share Video in to **Facebook, YouTube, Flicker, Vimeo** Take a look above link and test this Example.

You need to set You `AppId` in to `ESSViewController.m` class In this Method:

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender
{
    self.fb = [[[ESSFacebook alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                               appID:@"youAppID"
                                           appSecret:@"secret"] autorelease];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IMG_1203" withExtension:@"MOV"];
    [self.fb uploadVideoAtURL:url];
}
```

Might Be this is an Old virsion of Facebook but for getting Idea about how to process for share Video from ourApp.

Comment: where i pass the permission for  "publish_stream" & @"publish_actions"
beacause i get error after completed 100% upload everytime

{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Comment: recent facebook update. if you are creating app after 30 april you have to submit facebook app for review and u have to asking for publish_actions in reivew.

Answer (score 0):

All of your code after `NSURL *videourl` should be moved to another method. Currently it is being executed while the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:` request is in progress so the `facebookAccount` reference isn't available yet. So, the new method that you create and move that code to should be called from the `completion` block if `granted` is true.

Note hat you can't just immediately request publish permissions. You must request read permissions first and then, once it's been granted, request publish permissions.

Comment: Granted always returns false though, so I don't think it's just a time issue

Comment: What is the error message that's returned when access isn't granted?

Comment: it was just what i had above: error code 6. I tried googling it but didn't get much

Comment: Do you actually have an account setup in your device settings?

Comment: I added a url scheme row in the plist

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your NSDictionary creation.

```
   NSDictionary *options = @{
                           ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"2************",
                           ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                           ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
   };
```

you see you are passing keys first and objects later, where NSDictionary calls +dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys in this case...

try using the correct format like:

```
NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"###############", ACFacebookAppIdKey, 
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_stream"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey, 
                         nil];
```

this should work.

see the same question here:
[Getting "Error Code 8" When Calling [ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType] - iOS Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425325/getting-error-code-8-when-calling-acaccountstore-requestaccesstoaccountswitht)